# React Hook check if counter jumps from 5 (latest index) to 1 (first index)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my current I am was trying to check if the latest index (number 5) jumps to 1. Since I have built a function counter that automatically jumps to 1 when it reach the latest index, but I also want to have a check when it jumps from latest index to the first index...React Hook not necessarily needed for this issue....

```js
const App = ({ scoreCounter }) => {
    const boolean = useRef(null);
    const [ checkCounter, setCheckCounter ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const storedCounter = currentCounter;
        boolean.current = storedCounter;

        return () => storedCounter;
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(currentCounter == 5) {
            
        }
        console.log(boolean.current, currentCounter);

    }, [boolean.current, currentCounter])

    
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        currentCounter: state.game.counter 
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain your desired behavior in more detail? I am confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It would like a function that check if the fifth index jumps to first index....

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class components you can compare your `prevState` to your current `state` in the `componentDidUpdate` function. In hooks you can implement something similar with the example shown here: [usePrevious](https://usehooks.com/usePrevious/).

Using the usePrevious function in the link you can do this:

```
const prevCount = usePrevious(checkCounter);

// Hook
function usePrevious(value) {
  // The ref object is a generic container whose current property is mutable ...
  // ... and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class
  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (prevCount === 5 && checkCounter === 1) {
    // your code here
  }
}, [prevCount, checkCounter])
```